# Replicate unpack of perl in c++

Tags: c++, perl, pack, unpack

I have a binary string with ASCII like this

> ^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^O ^@^@^@^@^@^BÜ-^@^@^@^A^@^@^O ^@^@^@^@^@^BÜ-^@^@^@^A^@^@^*@^@^@^@^@^@^EÜ?^@^@^@^A^@^@^*@^@^@^@^@^@^EÜ?^@^@^@^A^@^@.à^@^@^@^@^@^Häð^@^@^@^A^@^@.à^@^@^@^@^@^Häð^@^@^@^A^@^@><80>^@^@^@^@^@^KÖ<80>^@^@^@^A^@^@><80>^

Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

open(INDEX, $ARGV[0]);
binmode(INDEX);

my $buff;

my $ret = read(INDEX, $buff, 4);
my $fragment = unpack 'N', $buff;

$ret = read(INDEX, $buff, 4);
my $timestamp = unpack 'N', $buff;

$ret = read(INDEX, $buff, 8);
my $offset = unpack 'N', $buff;

print "timestamp = $timestamp fragment # $fragment offset = $offset\n";
```

Output:

```
timestamp = 0 fragment # 1 offset = 0
timestamp = 0 fragment # 1 offset = 0
timestamp = 0 fragment # 1 offset = 0
timestamp = 0 fragment # 1 offset = 0
timestamp = 4000 fragment # 1 offset = 187437
timestamp = 4000 fragment # 1 offset = 187437
timestamp = 8000 fragment # 1 offset = 384063
timestamp = 8000 fragment # 1 offset = 384063
timestamp = 12000 fragment # 1 offset = 582896
timestamp = 12000 fragment # 1 offset = 582896
```

I want to replicate the above work done by unpack in C++
How to do it?

What I was trying:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int k;
    char buf1[5];
    char buf2[5];
    char buf3[9];
    int i;
    char *str;
    //Assume str contains the entire binary data

   for(int i=0;str[i];)
   {
        while(k<32)
    {
            buf1[k]=str[i];
            ++k;++i;
    }
    k=0;
    while(k<32)
    {
            buf2[k]=str[i];
            ++k;
    }
    k=0;
    while(k<64)
    {
            buf3[k]=str[i];
            ++k;++i;
    }
    k=0;
    uint32_t a1,b1,a2,b2;
    uint64_t a3,b3;
    a1=atoi(buf1);
    b1=ntohl(a1);

    a2=atoi(buf2);
    b2=ntohl(a2);

    a3=atoi(buf1);
    b3=ntohl(a3);

    print "timestamp ="<< b2 << "fragment #"<<b1<<" offset ="<<b3<<"\n";
    }
return 0;
```

}

Comment: I want the c++ code to do what perl script does!

Comment: 1) work out what each of the byte values represents, 2) read them in, 3) using insights from 1 reassemble them into the time values you want.  You can start with an `std::ifstream` to read from, and I'd guess that the values would be in some fairly standard format: you can probably read them directly into `uintint32_t` and might need to run [`ntohl`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl) over them.  Post your code ***when you've actually tried something*** and people will help you.

Comment: Sorry have added what I was doing.Can you correct me?

Comment: It would probably help a lot if you were to actually describe what you want. Saying "I have an unreadable mess of input and an equally unreadable mess of Perl" places the entire burden of making any sense of things on the reader. Your C++ is a lot better, but you still fail to tell us what you intended it to do, and how the results you get differ from what you wanted.

Comment: The Perl code is quite readable.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        cerr << "Input filename required" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    ifstream f( argv[1], ios::binary );
    if (!f.good())
    {
        cerr << "Cannot open input file '" << argv[1] << "'" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    while (!f.eof())
    {
        uint8_t buf[8];

        f.read( reinterpret_cast< char * >( buf ), 4 );
        uint32_t fragment = ( ( buf[0] * 256U + buf[1] ) * 256U + buf[2] ) * 256U + buf[3];

        f.read( reinterpret_cast< char * >( buf ), 4 );
        uint32_t timestamp = ( ( buf[0] * 256U + buf[1] ) * 256U + buf[2] ) * 256U + buf[3];

        f.read( reinterpret_cast< char * >( buf ), 8 );
        uint64_t offset = ( ( ( ( ( ( buf[0] * 256LL + buf[1] ) * 256LL + buf[2] ) * 256LL + buf[3] )
            * 256LL + buf[4] ) * 256LL + buf[5] ) * 256LL + buf[6] ) * 256LL + buf[7];

        if (f.good())
        {
            cout << "timestamp = " << timestamp;
            cout << " fragment = " << fragment;
            cout << " offset = " << offset << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Khouri Giordano!! It works like a charm.One small doubt.What if the input is stored in std::string instead of a file? In that case  what to use instead of                                    f.read( reinterpret_cast< char * >( buf ), 4 );                        f.read( reinterpret_cast< char * >( buf ), 4 );                        f.read( reinterpret_cast< char * >( buf ), 8 );                      am pretty new to C++,so forgive me if am asking basics

Comment: The whole point of `f.read( reinterpret_cast< char * >( buf ), 4 )` is to get the bytes into a string. You simply skip over the step and use the code I posted earlier.

Comment: ikegami..Two questions.. first,you have read from the file into a char array and then done left and right shift on it..is it fine? i executed your code,didnt get the wanted output so asking..second,you read from 1 to 4 bytes initially..after that want 4 to 8..then 8 to 16..this reading is from a string and not file..how to do that? I dont have the experience of coding so a fully working code will be really helpful. thanks in advance and sorry if am wrong

Comment: The problem is the use of `char` versus `uint8_t` or `unsigned char`. Whether `char` is unsigned or not is implementation defined, but usually this means it's signed. When doing arithmetic operations on `char`, it gets promoted to `int`. Any value above 127 will be interpreted as a negative value and have those bits extended to the size of an `int`, most likely 32 bits. The offset value is 64 bits and needs to be handled using `uint64_t`. This is why I multipled by 256U and 256LL. Now I notice that should be 256ULL. The compiler will probably optimize this to shifts so don't worry about that.

Comment: Thanks...what if my input is in a string and not a file.Can you tell how this code will change then?

Answer (score -1):

Read 4 bytes, then use

```
uint32_t n;
n = buf[0] << 24
  | buf[1] << 16
  | buf[2] <<  8
  | buf[3] <<  0;
```

For example,

```
uint32_t n;
unsigned char buf[4];
size_t bytes_read = fread (buf, 1, 4, stream);
if (bytes_read < 4) {
   if (ferror(stream)) {
      // Error
      // ...
   }
   else if (feof(stream)) {
      // Premature EOF
      // ...
   }
}
else {
   n = buf[0] << 24
     | buf[1] << 16
     | buf[2] <<  8
     | buf[3] <<  0;
}
```